# Importing slides at beginning and ending of the section of presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I was trying to import a two slides in existing presentation, but I wanted to import Slide 1 in beginning of the presentation and slide 2 at the end of the presentation.

Below are the script which I have worked on but not getting how to work on my above requirement

```
Sub Merge()
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

    'Set path to current dirrectory
    sPath = CurDir
    If Right$(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"

    'Set File Picker dialog
    Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(Type:=msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'Set initial path and view, set multiselect capability
    With dlgOpen
        .InitialFileName = "C:\G-Tools\Coverpage\WestRock_CoverPage.pptx"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
        .Title = "WestRock_CoverPage.pptx"
        .AllowMultiSelect = True

        'If user click on OK, insert selected files after last slide of current presentation
        If .Show = -1 And .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            For x = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
                ActivePresentation.Slides.InsertFromFile .SelectedItems(x), ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
            Next
        Else
            'User Cancelled
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

If anyone can help me with this it will be very great help for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're going to have to open the selected presentation to get single slides out of it. Your existing code would only allow the user to select several presentations, then insert all of them at one spot.

Comment: @JohnKorchok Is there any other script which i can use for that ?

Comment: Yes, there are lots. Googling 'powerpoint "vba" copy indvidual slides' gets pages of results that will guide you.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the keyword, John, it really help me to find what I was looking for